# How to get recently viewed product collection in observer Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, event-observer, recently-viewed

I want to fetch a recently viewed products collection in the observer and by using that collection I want to add my custom product in that collection.

### Following Things That I Want To Achieve.

1. On click of a product when it opens a product detail page that product id should be stored in session->**Completed**
2. After that, I want to add those products which are stored in session in recently viewed product collection when the user creates a new account display those products in the recently viewed product widget.->**Incomplete**

> **The main Thing Is that I want to display guest user recently viewed product to a new customer  when the guestuser  creates a new account**

Following Is Observer File

```
<?php 
 namespace Namespace\RecentProducts\Session;
 class ProductData 
  {

protected $_coreSession;
public function __construct(

    \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $coreSession

){
    $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
}

public function setValue($value){
$this->_coreSession->start();
$this->_coreSession->setMessage($value);
}

public function getValue(){
$this->_coreSession->start();
return $this->_coreSession->getMessage();
 }

public function unSetValue(){
$this->_coreSession->start();
return $this->_coreSession->unsMessage();
}


}


?>
```

Following is my session file where I am calling observers methods

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\RecentProducts\Observer\Product;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;



class Data implements ObserverInterface

{

public function execute(Observer $observer)

{


    $product = $observer->getProduct();

    $originalName = $product->getName();

    $imgdata = $product->getImage();

    $catid = $product->getCategoryId();

    $entid = $product->getEntityId();


    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

/*-------begining of code to set data to session----------*/
$SessionCollection =  $objectManager->get('Magneto\RecentProducts\Session\ProductData');
$value = $SessionCollection->getValue();
$newValue = explode(",",$value);
    if($value)
    {
        if(!in_array($entid,$newValue))
        {
            $newdata = $value.",".$entid;
            $SessionCollection->setValue($newdata);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        $SessionCollection->setValue($entid);

    }

    echo $value;

}
```

}

Following is events.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

<event name="catalog_controller_product_view">

    <observer name="RecentProductData" instance="Magneto\RecentProducts\Observer\Product\Data" />

</event>

</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your observer :

**Method 1 :**

```
/**
 * Layout
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface
 */

 protected $_layout;

 public function __construct(
    .....
    \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout
    .......
 ) {
     $this->_layout = $layout;
 }

public function getMyCollection() {
    $block =  $this->_layout->getBlockSingleton(\Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed::class)->getItemsCollection();
    return $block;
}
```

**Method 2 :**

You need to load **ItemCollection()** after get collection like below way :

```
protected $recentlyViewed;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed $recentlyViewed
) {
    $this->recentlyViewed = $recentlyViewed;
}

public function execute() {
    $collection = $this->recentlyViewed->getItemsCollection()->load();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($collection->getData());
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but not working

Comment: I have used your second method it returns blank array

Comment: I tried. It's working perfectly. Please make sure you have collection of recent view product or not and refresh statistics of that grid.

Comment: Yes I have a collection of recent product and also refresh the statistics default recent product is working when i show them using widget but in array it returns blank'

Comment: Any system or error log?

Comment: No there is no issue

Comment: Strange ..!!! :D

Comment: can you please tell me the file path from where magento fetches recent product data and check for condiion that this products are viewed by perticular customer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91203/discussion-between-harsh-jayswal-and-rohan-hapani).